# Qualtrics: Advanced Randomization now showing up all the questions

Tags: javascript, qualtrics, heap-randomization

I have a question block with one multiple choice question in it.

I want to randomly evenly display one choice per participant.

However when I click advanced randomization, only the title of the whole multiplie choice question shows up,

and all the choices doesn't show up.

What should I do??

[image]

[image]

I want to know the reason why no choices are showing up, and hopefully a solution for me to be able to randomly display one choice per time.

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise we won't be able to solve your issue.

Comment: @i-drink-dirty-code What code do you mean? there's no code I used in setting up this question.

Comment: Surely _someone_ must have written code for this web page to appear.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you've set up a Choice Group named ToDoAdvcies (the same as your question text), added all the choices to it, and hidden the group title. If that's the case, to fix it, right click on one of the choices then choose Parent Group Options -> Remove Group.

BTW, Stackoverflow is geared toward programming code, so this question doesn't really fit. The [Qualtrics Community](https://community.qualtrics.com/XMcommunity) would be a better forum for this type of question.